# NO CAPTURA TEXTO JTEXTFIELD

Tags: java

Buen dia tengo un JFrame con un panel y dentro un Jtextfield pero al ejecutar no puedo escribir dentro del Campo de texto. ya cheque y esta configurado como editable.
alguien que me pueda ayudar

---

[image: JTextField.]
El JTextField Lo Coloco desde el contenedor Swing, de echo tengo otras ventanas con mas JTextField y si me funcionan, dentro del panel tengo etiquetas que de echo desde codigo les asigno Background pero no funciona ahora el JTextField no me sirve solo esa caja de texto es la que no me funciona, tengo un JMenu arriba, abajo tengo un panel con etiquetas y el boton actualizar , la tabla, y el jtextfield que no me funciona

Comment: Si añadieras una porción de tu código sería más fácil poder ayudarte.

Comment: amigo comente una imagen

Comment: Amigo, te recomiendo revisar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Acá abajo sólo van los intentos de respuesta; tú puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/420736/edit) tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario para añadir la información que se necesite para ayudarte a resolver tu problema (usando el enlace *editar* bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas).

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que apenas empiezas a usar JFrame.

```
public class GraficaEjemplo{
 private JTexField input;
 public GraficaEjemplo(){
   //Para inicializar el objeto puedes ponerle parámetros o simplemente default.
   this.input = new JTextField();
   //El tamaño que quieres que tenga tu TextField
   this.input.setColumns(10);
   //Lo hablitas para que sea editable y si quieres le añades un valor previo o "" que seria el null de String 
   this.input.setEditable(true);
   this.input.setText("")
 }
 public imprimeAlgo(){
 //Con getText obtienes el valor ingresado en el formulario.
     System.out.println(this.input.getText())
 }

}
```

Si necesitas más información te recomiendo que visites la documentacion de Oracle [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) o esta otra página para algo más sencillo un [Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jtextfield/).

Espero te sirva de ayuda.